# Use bearer token with google cloud storage SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload a file into GCS using a bearer token, and I know how to do it using REST API, but is there a way to do it using Google's SDK?

Basically I want to translate the following REST API request to the SDK.

```py
def put_in_storage(bucket_name, blob_name, content, access_token, project)
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    url = f"https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{bucket_name}/o/?uploadType=multipart&project={project}&name={blob_name}"

    return requests.post(url, data=content, headers=headers)
```

Doing the following using Google's SDK (as I read [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guide.html#user-credentials))

```py
from google.oauth2.credentials Credentials
from google.cloud import storage

def put_in_storage(bucket_name, blob_name, content, access_token):
    credentials = Credentials(access_token)
    gcs_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
    bucket = gcs_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(data=content)
```

Only raises the following error

```bash
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

The reason I want to do it, is because the SDK wraps the upload type based on the file size (resumable/multipart).

Comment: How did you create the access token? This problem might be caused by not setting the JWT header **kid** Without the private key id, the project ID is required in order to look up the public certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding project id to the `Client` initiation solved the problem (inspired by [this discussion](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/2314) in Github)

```py
gcs_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```